# yii placeholder for filter

Tags: php, yii

In my `CGridview` filter section, I need to place placeholder. Is this possible in Yii?

Or is this possible by extending `CGridview` to accomodate `filterOptions` tag, which contains the place holder. If its, how to extend CGridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that extending class is need for this purpose,
just use

```
'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, attribute, 
                 array('placeholder'=>'place holder text'))),
```

Comment: I would like to extend cgridview.

Comment: Ok I was wrong, CGridView->filter must be declared and then in each column add the above sentence.