# putting placeholder in yii CGridview filter

Tags: yii

I need to have placeholders in textbox of filters in yii CGridView I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170870/yii-placeholder-for-filter) question but it is not working anybody has idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a code like in below of your grid view.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'product-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'product_name',
        'product.description',  
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Now you want to add placeholder to product_name, then you may change it above code to ....

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'product-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'id',
             array('name'=>'product_name', 'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'product_name',array("placeholder"=>"place holder text"))),        
            'product.description',
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
    )); ?>
```

Secondly, if you want to add place holders for all columns then if you adding it in CGridView code then you should have to add separately but i think you may add it to use by CSS by adding property for that specific columns.
Check the link below too.
[How to set placeholder value using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075986/how-to-set-placeholder-value-using-css)

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: I used to do this using JS, this way is far better.

Answer (score 1):

Structure like below is working copy .

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'car-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'manufacturer',
        array('name'=>'model','value'=>'$data->model',
                    'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'model',array("placeholder"=>"place holder text"))),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Please check properly, set 'filter' above and below like in this code sample .

Comment: is there any way to have same placeholder for all columns without going into details of columns